# Excel pivot and chart - hiding field from the chart

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

Hi have this pivot table 
the pivot table is basically as follows

Project1 - 01/01/2010 | some data
Project2 - 01/06/2010 | some data
Project3 - 01/05/2010 | some data
Project4 - 01/04/2010 | some data
Project5 - 01/03/2010 | some data
Project6 - 01/02/2010 | some data

The project dash date is a concatenation of two column in the original dataset
I want the pivot to sort by date

I can add the date to the pivot table so  it is sorted by date. Like bellow.

01/01/2010 | Project1 - 01/01/2010 | some data
01/02/2010 | Project6 - 01/02/2010 | some data
01/03/2010 | Project5 - 01/03/2010 | some data
01/04/2010 | Project4 - 01/04/2010 | some data
01/05/2010 | Project3 - 01/05/2010 | some data
01/06/2010 | Project2 - 01/06/2010 | some data

but then my chart shows redundant data. Is there  a way to keep the date in the pivot only for sorting purpose. but my chart does not need to show the extra date ??

I tried removing the concatenation, and just show the pivot as is. But I am still having problem because having two X axis  only allowed one of the axis to be displayed vertically 
UNLESS I can make both X axis to be displayed vertically then I am satisfied

thanks for the input

Comment: you can get away from the concatenation by "Repeating All Label Items" in the Report Layout section of the pivot table design tab of the ribbon. That way you would add the date and project, and they would display like a normal table (each row containing each label)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to just went with simple solution . and sort it as text

BEFORE 
Project1 - 01/01/2010 | some data
Project2 - 01/06/2010 | some data
Project3 - 01/05/2010 | some data
Project4 - 01/04/2010 | some data
Project5 - 01/03/2010 | some data
Project6 - 01/02/2010 | some data

AFTER 
2010/01/01 - Project1 | some data
2010/02/01 - Project6 | some data
2010/03/01 - Project5 | some data
2010/04/01 - Project4 | some data
2010/05/01 - Project3 | some data
2010/06/01 - Project2 | some data

it works for my purpose.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you should be able to just remove the data series you don't want from your chart, after creating it. Not all the fields have to be displayed in a Pivot Chart, just leave out the ones you don't want (the date field used only to sort the table).

Comment: if I remove date field from pivot chart. my sorting get all over the place again.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Power Pivot Add-In for this requirement.  It has a Sort by Column feature to do exactly what you want.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/jessmeats/archive/2012/06/12/powerpivot-sort-by-column.aspx